# counting number of arithmetic progressions in an array

Tags: math

My previous qs. was unclear so I am again putting it in clear terms.
I need an efficient algorithm to count the number of arithmetic progressions in a series. The number of elements in a single AP should be >2. 
eg. if the series is {1,2,2,3,4,4} then the different solutions are listed  below(with index numbers):

```
0,1,3
0,2,3
0,1,3,4
0,1,3,5
0,2,3,4
0,2,3,5
hence the answer should be 6
```

I am not able to code it when these numbers become large and size of array increases. I need an efficient algorithm for this.

Comment: You couldn't just clarify your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you answer is incorrect. Numbers 2,3,4 (indexes also 2,3,4) form an AP.

Second, here is a simple brute force algorithm:

```
def find (vec,value,start):
    for i from start to length(vec):
        if vec[i] == value:
           return i
    return None

for i from 0 to length(vec) - 2:
    for j from i to length(vec) - 1:
        next = 2 * vec[j] - vec[i] # the next element in the AP
        pos = find(vec,next,j+1)
        if pos is None:
            continue
        print "found AP:\n %d\n %d\n %d" % (i,j,pos)
        prev = vec[j]
        here = next
        until (pos = find(vec,next = 2*here-prev,pos+1)) is None:
          print ' '+str(pos)
          prev = here
          here = next
```

I don't think you can do better than this `O(n^4)` because the total number of APs to be printed is `O(n^4)` (consider a vector of zeros).

If, on the other hand, you want to only print *maximal* APs, i.e., APs which are not contained in any other AP, then the problem becomes much more interesting...

Comment: Is there any way of counting all those sequences which are NOT AP's. And if yes, can its complexity be better then O(n^4)? pls help

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. the number of "sequences which are NOT AP" is far beyond that!